# What is the relationship between SmartTarget and Fredhopper?

Tags: 2013, smarttarget, fredhopper

What is the relationship between SmartTarget and Fredhopper?

As per user manual guide, for installing SmartTarget 2011 we require to install Fredhopper Access Server.

If we are installing SmartTarget 2014, do we need to install Fredhopper as well or will it be install automatically as part of SmartTarget 2014?

Could you please provide any useful points or links to install SmartTarget 2014 for more understanding the concept in detail.

Answer (score 7):

**Fredhopper:** SDL Fredhopper is a Customer Experience Management tool which provides a seamless, targeted and fully personalized website experience to the end users.
The SDL Fredhopper enables the marketing team to target a specific segment of customer with all the right products or content which suits them best.

**SmartTarget:** SmartTarget is an add-on for SDL Tridion which integrates SDL Tridion with SDL Fredhopper. SmartTarget acts as a bridge between SDL Tridion and SDL Fredhopper so that Marketers can create, update and manage targeted and personalized content for SDL Tridion driven website.

You can refer this post of mine for very basic understanding:

- [Sdl-fredhopper-and-smart-target](http://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/sdl-fredhopper-and-smart-target/)

You can also refer the official documentation of SDL (requires Login):

- [SmartTarget](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?c=t&action=home&pub=SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1&lang=en-US)
- [Fredhopper](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?c=t&action=home&pub=SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A835CC68-B349-4D04-93AD-D3D6EBD7F73B&filename=GUID-A835CC68-B349-4D04-93AD-D3D6EBD7F73B.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A835CC68-B349-4D04-93AD-D3D6EBD7F73B)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the actual question Pankaj, which is whether FHAS needs to be installed separately or is part of the ST install.

Comment: FHAS needs to be there, either on premise (installed before SmartTarget), or in the cloud. Here's the [link explaining the separate install in step 2](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-8BDDDAAD-BB27-4150-9121-C3283EA5A0C8) with "Download and install the Fredhopper Deployment Package."

Comment: @Nick: It absolutely address the question as per my understanding - The title of the question asked for the relationship between Fredhopper and Smart Target. Also the question asks for various useful links for clarification in concept. Regarding the other query in the question, if someone reads these concepts, it will automatically got resolved

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the information provided by Pankaj, here is my view on this:

**You need to install Fredhopper separately from SDL SmartTarget.** However, as Peter points out in the comments, this can be done before or after SmartTarget, as long as both are configured correctly afterwards.

Fredhopper is an 'engine' that was traditionally used on eCommerce sites to provide intelligent navigation, search (including faceted search) and product listings.

SDL SmartTarget is a relatively new product (compared to Tridion and Fredhopper) that provides an integration between Tridion and Fredhopper. It makes use of the Fredhopper 'engine', to extend on the tradition eCommerce functionality, and provide targeted/personalised content for your website end users.

Installing SmartTarget provides an extra 'Targeting' interface alongside the Tridion Content Management Explorer (CME) that allows users to create `Promotions` for this targeted content.

[image]

It also provides some functionality for adding the Promotions and targeted content into Fredhopper, as well as a dedicated SmartTarget API for querying the content...

... but, the Fredhopper Application Server (FAS) has to be installed separately.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter too much, but technically you can install Fredhopper after SmartTarget -- you just won't get everything working until both are successfully installed and configured. Just wanted to clarify that in case someone had installed SmartTarget first - you don't need to uninstall it in that case, just add Fredhopper next.

Comment: Ah, thanks Peter. I will update my answer to say that Fredhopper needs to be installed separately, but not necessarily first.